# CollectionViewLayout Height

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I want to custom a lot of layout size for each row of my `collectionView` by using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` like below:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = view.frame.width
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: width, height: 300)
        }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            return dynamicSize // i want this size wrap its content
        }
        return CGSize(width: width, height:100)
}
```

I want dynamicSize that can wrap its content for some row.
Anyone know how to do this?

Here is image of cell that i want dynamic size to wrap it.

[image]

Comment: Yeah we know but first show us your final ui.

Comment: I have update question with add image below, please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use tableview instead of collectionview. It is very easy for you.

And for `cellForHeight` returns `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. It will calculate your cell height itself and adjust it accordingly.

**Note:** Make sure your constraints are proper.

> Edit: By using collectionview with two columns.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var text = "Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib."

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{

        let cellWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 10
        let textHeight = text.height(withConstrainedWidth: cellWidth, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16))
        let constantHeight : CGFloat = 40 + 25 + 10 // top name view + bottom like button + margins height
        let totHeight = constantHeight + textHeight

        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: totHeight)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        cell.label.text = text
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        return cell
    }

}

extension String {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }

    func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)

        return ceil(boundingBox.width)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Before i do it in tableView and it's work fine for me. But it's has more special cell that i need to change  it to use collectionView. Do you have any other good idea?

Comment: Can you specify why you need to use collectionview?

Comment: I need row that have 2 columns.

Comment: @Brorsoeu.Sen Make sure your constraints are proper else you face some new issues. Just keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Use this delegate method. this will work for me.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       return CGSize(width: Your cellWidth, height: YourcellHeight);
    }
```

Comment: "YourcellHeight" seem like a static value, i need dynamic value for wrap my content.

Comment: Basically your cell height and width base on your design. so i had provide you just delegate for this.

Comment: Your answer is what I wrote in my question! Did you see it?